# Disable interpolation in Javascript image size scale

Tags: javascript, image, size, scale, interpolation

Yes, how to disable the image scaling blur and make it pixelated. Have been searching but didn't find a solution.

Comment: With [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) which is CSS and has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: I've tried that, not a difference. I'm drawing the images via JavaScript (canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage)